# Angular UI Router: Redirect all sub states

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI Router and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to redirect all sub states using `$stateProvider`.

For example, if the user visits any `/contact` state:

```
/contact/foo
/contact/bar
/contact/baz
```

They will always get redirected to `/contact/about`.

My states are set up like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contact', {
  url: '/contact',
  component: 'contact',
  redirectTo: 'contact.about'
})
.state('contact.about', {
  url: '/contact/about',
  component: 'contactAbout',
});
```

Is there a way to redirect all states to `contact.about` that follow this pattern: `/contact/ANY_PATH`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this. Each way assumes ui-router 1.0+

#### State with parameter

```
$stateProvider
.state('contact', {
  url: '/contact',
  component: 'contact',
  redirectTo: 'contact.about'
})
.state('contact.wildcard', {
  url: '/{rest:.*}',
  redirectTo: { state: 'contact.about', options: { replace: true } },
})
.state('contact.about', {
  url: '/about',
  component: 'contactAbout',
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zfhEsWYP5LPmxbaULNVT?p=preview

#### URL .when rule

```
  $urlServiceProvider.rules.when('/contact/{rest:.*}', '/contact/about', { priority: -1 });

  $stateProvider
  .state('contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    component: 'contact',
    redirectTo: 'contact.about'
  })
  .state('contact.about', {
    url: '/about',
    component: 'contactAbout',
  });
```

The `priority: -1` ensures that the state's url matches after the redirect, instead of the `.when` rule firing again.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gGFzNUMUqj4vGwXKX8ui?p=preview

Comment: These are great! Didn't know how to do it with state in option 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**There is 2 question**

1. **If our `state` is exist**

   ```
   /contact/foo
   /contact/bar
   /contact/baz
   ```

   if you have those `states` in your `app.config` you don't need to redirect it because you can set same template of `contact.about`.

---

2. **If our `state` is not exist**

   ```
   /contact/foo
   /contact/bar
   /contact/baz
   ```

but what if you don't have those `states` in your app?

in this case your `ui-router` redirect it dynamically to `otherwise` state.

**solution**

In the state events of `ui-router` we can find `"$stateNotFound"` to help us, so we can create a simple **dictionary of not exist states** `which if this state not exist direct to x state`.

**Main Controller**

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$state", function ($state) {
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   $state.go(pathname);
}]);
```

> To detect if user edit the URL manual, we use `$state.go` in controller just for calling the `$stateNotFound` on `app.run` *(this case)*

**app.run**

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateNotFound", function (event, unfoundState) {
  event.preventDefault();

  switch (unfoundState.to) {
    case "/contact/foo":
        window.location.replace("/contact/about");
        break;
    case "/contact/bar":
        window.location.replace("/contact/about");
        break;
    case "/contact/baz":
        window.location.replace("/contact/about");
        break;
  }
});
```